# How to add columns of one DataFrame to another DataFrame when these 2 DataFrames have common columns that contain exactly the same values?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have 2 DataFrames that share 2 same columns (same column names and entries). Both of them have additional columns that are totally different:

df1:

```
data1 = {
  "name": ["Sally", "Sally", "Micky", "Sally", "Sally", "Micky"],
  "age": [77, 44, 22, 0,0,0],
  "gender":["F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M"]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

[image]

df2:

```
data2 = {
  "name": ["Sally", "Sally", "Micky", "Sally", "Sally", "Micky"],
  "age": [77, 44, 22,0,0,0],
  "home": ["Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y"]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

[image]

Now I want to merge these 2 DataFrames based on the common columns "name" and "age" without generating additional rows.

**One thing to pay attention to:**
the entries of the common columns have duplicates and they need to stay untouched (no risk of losing them).

My current codes:

```
newdf = df2.merge(df1, how='inner')
```

However, this coding generates 2 more rows that are unexpected:

[image]

What should I do to have the rows (after merging) stay the same as df1 and df2?

Comment: If df1 and df2 have same `name` and `age` , you can just add the extra column from df2 to df1 by : 

    df1['home'] = df2['home']

Comment: That is a very good idea. My only concern is that the 2 real DataFrames both contain 2893 rows and I am not 100% sure that they are in the same order, so I was thinking to avoid mismatching risk. Do you think that risk exists?

Comment: If you want to merge in order: `cols = ['name', 'age'] ; out = df1.merge(df2, left_on=cols+[df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()], right_on=cols+[df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()])`. Then no risk of mis-alignment.

Comment: Would you please make it an answer? I would like to accept it.

Comment: @Bella this virtually the same as in the linked duplicate. If you want you can vote on my answer in the duplicate, but there is no point in copy/pasting it again here. Your question remains useful for future readers though as it will help them find the answer in the duplicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df=pd.merge(df1,df2,on = ['name', 'age'], how = 'left')
df=df.drop_duplicates()
```

This gives:

```
df
    name  age gender home
0  Sally   77      F    Y
1  Sally   44      F    N
2  Micky   22      M    N
3  Sally    0      F    N
5  Sally    0      M    N
7  Micky    0      M    Y
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way to perform the merge. Imagine having 1000 duplicates, you'll create 1M intermediate rows for nothing…